# How to populate ManyToMany field with POST request in FastAPI

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, fastapi, pydantic

Having this models with ManyToMany relation in FastAPI app. I need to populate `sent_log` table with data from POST request:

```
{
"user_id": 1
"article_id": 2
}
```

models.py

```
   sent_log = Table(
        "sent_log",
        Base.metadata,
        Column("user_id", ForeignKey("users.id"), primary_key=True),
        Column("article_id", ForeignKey("articles.id"), primary_key=True),
        Column('sent_time', DateTime(), server_default=text('NOW()')),
    )


class User(Base):
    """User model. Has Many2Many relationship with Article."""

    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    telegram_id = Column(Integer, unique=True, index=True)
    username = Column(String(50))
    pet_name = Column(String(50))
    language_code = Column(String(5))
    # date_join = Column(DateTime(), server_default=text('NOW()')),

    sent_articles = relationship(
        "Article", secondary=sent_log, back_populates="sent_to_user"
    )


class Article(Base):
    """Article model. Has Many2Many relationship with User."""

    __tablename__ = "articles"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    text = Column(String(1024))
    image_url = Column(String(500))
    language_code = Column(String(255), index=True)

    sent_to_user = relationship(
        "User", secondary=sent_log, back_populates="sent_articles"
    )
```

How to make it in crud.py?

Comment: https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/many-to-many/update-remove-relationships/

Comment: https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/many-to-many/create-data/

Comment: I need to use SQLAlchemy, not SQLModel